# Why is the program showing a 404 error.. The HTML page when clicked

Tags: servlets, sample

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>FirstProject</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletClass1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.ServletClass1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletClass1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/first.*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

first.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="f1" action="first" method="get">
      <input type="text" name=t/>
      <button value="Click" type="submit"></button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

ServletClass1.java

```
package com.test;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ServletClass1 extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();  
        String msg = request.getParameter("t");
        out.println("the msg is"+msg);  
    }
}
```

Comment: When you manually want to send the response you should call `out.flush()` to commit the response. Also, when manually outputting the response like this, you will never reach the `first.html` page

Comment: i keep the response in HTML tags..Now why is the program not executing?

Comment: But you have both a servlet, and a physical file, mapped to first.html, even if it worked, it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: If you're web context root is used correct and you surf to `first.html` these settings should invoke your `ServletClass1.doGet` method, but it never commits its response using `flush`, so nothing is being send to the server!

Comment: @jb10210 am able to reach first.html.. After submitting the form, it is giving an 404 error

Comment: Well yeah, you're submitting to "first", which has no mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<form action>` URL needs to match the `<url-pattern>` of the servlet mapping. Right now it doesn't. Fix your servlet mapping `<url-pattern>` as follows:

```
<url-pattern>/first</url-pattern>
```

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - Contains some Hello World examples

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, please make sure that you aren't reading heavily outdated resources/books/tutorials. Your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 2.4 which is almost 9 years old already. We're since 2.5 years already on Servlet 3.0.

Comment: Thankq all for the replies. The program did execute.